# What is the reference of "from" in this sentence?

Tags: translation, interpretation

Below, you can see page 77 of [ST_Lite_JxE081_v00.02](https://www.commoncriteriaportal.org/files/epfiles/ST_Lite_JxE081_v00.02.pdf) .It is a Security-Target (a document that indicate some security specification of an IT production) for *JCOP Smart cards.*

[image]

**TSF = Target Security Functions**

In the sentece that I underlined above, what is the reference of "From"? It refers to *interpretation* or it refers to to *TSF data*? In the other word, which of these below interpretation is true?

1. using another trusted IT product to interpret the TSF data
2. interpreting the data of TSF that comes from another IT product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your second option is the right one:

> Interepreting the TSF data that **comes from** another trusted IT product

I did not understand your first option:

> interpreting from another trusted IT product the data of TSF

Did you mean to say

> When using another trusted IT product to interpret the TSF data

Comment: Yes I was meant the same that you said in last line. Why it is not true? I correct it.

Comment: @TheGoodUser-Amir -- I see. In English, you can say "I saw her **from** the train", but it would be awkward to say "I processed this data file **from** my favorite program". One tends to apply the word **using** in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

Number 2 is correct.

...interpreting X. 
Where X = another product's TSF data

A and B are parallel in meaning here:

A...interpreting the TSF data from another IT product.

B...enjoying the light from the sun.

----> shows 
origin/source       -----(object)--->

Another IT product  -----(TSF data)--->

Sun                 ----(light)--->

Comment: I just understand your first line! :D _Number 2 is correct_

Comment: I did not read your question correctly the first time. Yes, the answer is 2. The reference connected to *from* is *TSF data.*